# How do I recover files that vanished because I marked them as "podcast"?

Tags: iphone, itunes

I'm using iTunes 12.6.1.25 on Windows 8.1, trying to write files to an iPhone 5c.

I have a set of podcast files as .mp3s that I have attempted to add to the iPhone through iTunes. Once added to the iPhone's music library in iTunes, I can right-click the file and select "Get Info" to view its metadata dialog.  On the "Options" tab of that dialog is a drop-down menu labeled "media kind", which is automatically set to "Music" when I add these files to the library.

If I change this setting to "Podcast" in a futile attempt to get iTunes to sort them properly, the file disappears from the library.  It exists nowhere else, even if I switch to the iTunes "Podcast" library.  The iPhone itself doesn't have a "Podcast" library, so I can't look there.  If I attempt to add this file to the library again, it won't add - it just doesn't show up.

I ejected the iPhone and restarted iTunes, but that doesn't help. iTunes seems to remember the file as "Podcast" instead of "Music", so that effectively I can never, ever load this file onto the iPhone and listen to it.

How can I coerce iTunes into displaying or replacing this lost file?

Comment: The iPhone has a Podcasts app. Do they appear there? If you don't have the default podcasts app, you might have to re-download it from the App Store. (As a side note, I would recommend using Overcast for podcasts over the default app)

Comment: @Christian I don't have that app, so I can't check.  This is an iTunes problem, though - even *before* I sync to the iPhone, iTunes will not recognize or show the file.  I need iTunes to display the file independently of the phone.